# checking if the input is int >=0 using if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
IDnum = input("\nprompt: ")

if int(IDnum) >= 0 :
    if int(IDnum) in T.keys() :
        print("ID number(s) that {} will contact is(are) {}.".format(int(IDnum),T[int(IDnum)]))
    else :
        print("Entered ID number {} does not exist.".format(int(IDnum)))
else:
    break
```

It's actually a while loop, receiving ID numbers and checking whether the numbers are in the file.

I'd like to make it discern whether the input is an integer >= 0 and if it's anything else, (eg. space,enter,characters,float,etc) break the loop.

How can I do this using if statements?

I have tried 
    if IDnum == '' or IDnum == ' ' or int(IDnum) < 0 :
but as you know, it cannot cover all the other cases.

Comment: I would simply go with `input_string.strip().isdigit()` to check for a positive integer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach But that would mean going through the num string twice, once for validation and another for conversion

Comment: @comiventor I think it's the most readable and simple code.  Performance doesn't matter at all here (and note that throwing an exception is rather slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T = {1: 1, 2: 2}
while True:
    IDnum = input("\nprompt: ")
    try:
        num = int(IDnum)
        if num < 0:
            raise ValueError('Negative Integers not allowed')
    except ValueError: # parsing a non-integer will result in exception
        print("{} is not a valid positive integer.".format(IDnum))
        break

    if num in T:
        print("ID number(s) that {} will contact is(are) {}.".format(num,T[num]))
    else:
        print("Entered ID number {} does not exist.".format(num))
```

Thanks to @adirio and @moses-koledoye for the suggested improvements.

Comment: Would suggest getting most of the code out of the try clause and use an else clause, to avoid silently failing on `ValueError`s inside the inner `if`.

Comment: @Adirio there was an extra else without if in your suggestion. I tried to improve it but not sure why SO just completely removed credit to you :(

Comment: The else was fine, it belonged to the try except else statement, look for that kind of statements

Answer (score 0):

Do the check with a try-except statement.

```
def is_pos_int(IDnum):
    ''' Check if string contains non-negative integer '''
    try:
        number = int(IDnum)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    if number >= 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For example

```
is_pos_int('1 ') # notice the space

Out[12]: True

is_pos_int('-1')

Out[13]: False

is_pos_int('1.0')

Out[15]: False

is_pos_int('word')

Out[16]: False
```

Then:

```
while True:
    if not is_pos_int(IDnum):
        break
    else:
        val = int(IDnum)
        if val in T.keys() :
            print("ID number(s) that {} will contact is(are) {}.".format(val, T[val]))
        else :
            print("Entered ID number {} does not exist.".format(val))
```